# Retargeting platform toolset

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I recently downloaded a project from GitHub which I need in my Visual Studio Solution. However the project was built with a different platform toolset: Visual Studio 2017 - Windows XP (v141_xp) (not installed). Compiling wouldn't work because the toolset required isn't installed.

Q: As I have Visual Studio 2017 with platform toolset (v141) can I tweak the project so that it will no longer ask for v141_xp toolset ? 
I searched for a way to solve the problem(I really need that project), but the only suggestion so far is to create a new solution with my default toolset and import everything manually from the downloaded project(which is pretty big).

Comment: Just change the toolset selection, still targeting XP doesn't make sense. Project > Properties > General.  If you must absolutely have it then re-run the installer and add "Windows XP support for C++".

Comment: @magicandre1981 posted this solution , however it doesn't compile this way either.

Comment: It is not my project,but I need ut and it was developed on this toolset.However I solved installing the XP support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a rightclick on the project in Solution Explorer inside VS2017, open properties and change the `Platform Toolset` from `v141_xp` to `v141`

[image]